# Parent Spring Application Context with CXFServlet and Jersey Spring Servlet

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, ejb

I'm working on some code to use a JEE6 MDB in mostly Spring application.  There is some thought on how WAS controls MDBs better than Spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer.  Anyway,  so far I've been able to put it all together, EJB deploys, Spring starts up, but when I get to the Servlets for CXF and Jersey, they both fail with the same relative error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context attribute is not of type WebApplicationContext: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Apr 29 17:16:26 CDT 2014]; parent: ApplicationContext 'parentContext'
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:82)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.getDefaultContext(SpringServlet.java:153)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.getContext(SpringServlet.java:137)
at com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet.initiate(SpringServlet.java:117)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Context attribute is not of type WebApplicationContext: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon Apr 28 16:20:56 CDT 2014]; parent: ApplicationContext 'parentContext'
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:99)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet.loadBus(CXFServlet.java:52)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.init(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:66)
```

To note: my CXFServlet is before Jersey's SpringServlet and I commented out the CXF to get past the error.

In order to couple the EJB and Spring I'm using the SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor and I have a parent context to the WebApplicationContext.

web.xml

```
    <!-- Tell Spring it's configuration file -->
<display-name>Customer Services</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
    <param-value>parentContext</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:spring-web.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <display-name>Customer Services Initializer</display-name>
    <listener-class>customer.maf.CustomerServicesInitializer</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <display-name>Spring Context Loader</display-name>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>config-location</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/cxf-beans.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jersey-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
<!-- and more configuration -->
```

I'm using Spring 3.0.7.RELEASE.  Deploying to WAS 8.5.5.  I thought I would create my own CXFServlet and override the logic, but then I hit the Jersey error and thought I'm probably doing something just not right.

Has anyone run across this situation before and how to did you fix it?

Comment: According to the Spring API doc, http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html, you only need to add that to the web.xml if you use a file other than beanRefContext.xml.  I'm using a beanRefContext.xml file on my classpath.

Comment: That's correct. Is your parentContextKey value matching with bean id of ClassPathXmlApplicationContext in beanRefContext.xml?

Comment: Also, try specifying <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> for jersey-servlet and <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup> for CXFServlet

Comment: parentContextKey value is the same as the name of the bean for the ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.  I don't see what the load-on-startup is going to do as I get the error from both classes.

Comment: Purpose of specifying that is to load jersey servlet first and then cxf.

Comment: Yes I know how it works. I'm telling you that it won't make a difference because I get the same exception from both servlets.

Answer (score 0):

parentContextKey and locatorFactorSelector params are required for obtaining/loading parent context. Parent context is usually required when you are having multiple war in an ear where common service related code for all all wars will be in parent context.  When you are using parentContextkey, you need to have the locatorFactorSelector param as well. "locatorFactorySelector" will contain the xml file which contains the spring service layer beans. As shown below, it points to beanRefContext.xml.

```
    <!-- Tell Spring it's configuration file -->
    <display-name>Customer Services</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:spring-web.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
        <param-value>parentContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
         <param-name>locatorFactorySelector</param-name>
         <param-value>classpath:beanRefContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

beanRefContext.xml which will have reference to service-layer-context.xml which holds service layer beans.

```
    <beans>
      <bean id="parentContext" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
        <constructor-arg>
          <list>
            <value>service-layer-context.xml</value>
          </list>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
    </beans>
```

So make sure to have appropriate beans are in service-layer-context.xml and make it a parent context which can be accessible by root and dispatcher and other web application contexts. If you think, your project don't have any parent context, remove parentContextKey context param.